# Castle Windsor - Linq to SQL Session Per Request and DataLoadOptions

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, castle-windsor

Using Castle Windsor to manage Linq to SQL DataContext with lifetime of per web:

```
Component.For<MyDataContext>()
                    .ImplementedBy<MyDataContext>()
                    .LifestylePerWebRequest()
```

Problem is that I need to eager load some child collections and from time to time and cannot set the DataLoadOptions once the context has returned some results.

> Setting load options is not allowed after results have been returned
>   from a query.

Only option I can see is to set the options in the constructor:

```
public SomeController(MyDataContext context)
{
_context = context;

var options = new DataLoadOptions();
            options.LoadWith<MyEntity>(x => x.Children);
            _context.LoadOptions = options;
}
```

Any tips or advice on how to handle this situation greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

L2S does not allow for modification of the fetch strategy after the context has been opened. No matter how you will have to work around this issue. Your solution will work, however another thing you can do is to derive the context and apply your eager loading in the derived one. This way you can inject an already set up instance in your controller.

You can also consider using a different ORM tool, one that supports modifying the load behaviour at a later stage (EF, OpenAccess, NHibernate). It shouldn't be too hard to convert if you have a small model.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Problem is that this is an existing application and cannot change the ORM. Normally used NH and very happy with it. The derived solution could work, but could get out of control with maintenance. May just new up a DataContext as needed in relevant sections.

Comment: I would assume the objects you need are just for read purposes. It could be troublesome if you try to update an object you have retrieved from another context. 

If you don't plan to use them for updates, a new context would work just fine, with almost no effort at all.